# online vs offline model performance

Tags: machine-learning, validation, online-algorithms

I work in a group that deploys models that are trained offline and evaluated offline before being deployed. THis is for an ads ranking system.

We also record whether the user clicked on our prediction or not. At times, we find that the online performance is much worse than what we had found in the offline performance.

When we detect such a case, we investigate by looking at differences between the offline validation/test datasets vs the online traffic that performed poorly.

I wanted to understand whether there is a systematic approach that others take to tackle this problem

Comment: This paper talks about this issue and provides some suggestions. "Predictive Model Performance:Offline and Online Evaluations" http://chbrown.github.io/kdd-2013-usb/kdd/p1294.pdf